# Dropdown menu can't open in another browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have create sidebar menu with dropdown, dropdown menu is fine with browser that I used to develop website. But when I used another browser dropdown menu can't appear. Also notification menu can't show up when I hover on another browser.

Browser I used is Google Chrome

Here is Sidebar html

```
<li><a href="#exampledropdownDropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse">Master Data </a>
          <ul id="exampledropdownDropdown" class="collapse list-unstyled ">
            <li> <a href="supplier.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Data Supplier</a></li>
              <li>  <a href="rpc.php"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Kategori RPC</a></li>
              <li>  <a href="list_part_umum.php"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> List Part Alokasi</a></li>
                <li>  <a href="hardware.php"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Daftar Hardware</a></li>
                  <li>  <a href="akun_transaksi.php"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Akun Transaksi</a></li>
                  <li>  <a href="catatan.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Business Note</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Here is the CSS

```
/*
* ==========================================================
*     SIDEBAR
* ==========================================================
*/
nav.side-navbar {
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  color: #686a76;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 9;
  /*==== Sidebar Header ====*/
  /*==== Sidebar Menu ====*/
  /*==== Shrinked Sidebar ====*/
}

nav.side-navbar a {
  color: inherit;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

nav.side-navbar a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
  content: '\f104';
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
}

nav.side-navbar a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background: #EEF5F9;
}

nav.side-navbar a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\f107';
}

nav.side-navbar a i {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

nav.side-navbar a .badge {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav.side-navbar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 30px 15px;
}

nav.side-navbar .avatar {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

nav.side-navbar .title {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

nav.side-navbar .title h1 {
  color: #333;
}

nav.side-navbar .title p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #aaa;
}

nav.side-navbar span.heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

nav.side-navbar ul {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

nav.side-navbar ul li {
  /* submenu item active */
}

nav.side-navbar ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

nav.side-navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: #796AEE;
  border-left: 4px solid #3b25e6;
  color: #fff;
}

nav.side-navbar ul li li a {
  padding-left: 50px;
  background: #EEF5F9;
}

nav.side-navbar ul li.active > a {
  background: #796AEE;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 4px solid #3b25e6;
}

nav.side-navbar ul li.active > a:hover {
  background: #796AEE;
}

nav.side-navbar ul li li.active > a {
  background: #8e81f1;
}

nav.side-navbar ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked {
  min-width: 90px;
  max-width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked span.heading {
  margin: 0;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li a {
  padding: 15px 2px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #aaa;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s, background 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s, background 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
  content: '\f107';
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li a[data-toggle="collapse"][aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\f106';
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li a:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li a i {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked ul li.active > a i {
  color: #fff;
}

nav.side-navbar.shrinked .sidebar-header .title {
  display: none;
}

/* SIDEBAR MEDIAQUERIES ----------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  nav.side-navbar {
    margin-left: -90px;
    min-width: 90px;
    max-width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  nav.side-navbar span.heading {
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li a {
    padding: 15px 2px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #aaa;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s, background 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s, background 0.3s;
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
    content: '\f107';
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li a[data-toggle="collapse"][aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\f106';
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li a:hover i {
    color: #fff;
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li.active > a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  nav.side-navbar ul li.active > a i {
    color: #fff;
  }
  nav.side-navbar .sidebar-header .title {
    display: none;
  }
  nav.side-navbar.shrinked {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .content-inner {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .content-inner.active {
    width: calc(100% - 90px);
  }
}
```

I used bootstrap and template bootstrapious

[Menu can show up when I used browser that I used to develop website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KduBW.png)

[Menu and modal can't show up on another browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6qsL.png)

Comment: We can't debug screenshots.

Comment: It's impossible for us to help without seeing your code. Also what browser worked and what browser didn't work. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask